# django - Filter foreign key against object

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Is the following query correct?

```
a = Blog.objects.get(id__exact=14)
b = Entry.objects.filter(blog = a)
```

I comprehend that that any of the following methods are more elegant and even recommended.

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog__id__exact=3) # Explicit form
Entry.objects.filter(blog__id=3)        # __exact is implied
Entry.objects.filter(blog__pk=3)        # __pk implies __id__exact
```

In other words, can I pass an object (model instance) as an argument value?

Please also provide some guidance on where can find explicit documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

```
a = Blog.objects.get(pk=3)
b = a.blog_set.all()
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, according to the django docs; you can use the instance of a row to do a filter.

[Queries over related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#queries-over-related-objects)

Comment: The link is broken